# Zoom won't launch on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, crash, deb, zoom-meeting

Yesterday I installed Zoom on my laptop and worked perfectly. Today, when I wanted to launch it again, it doesn't launch. I installed it using this command:

```
sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb
```

and it was installed without errors. I tried reinstalling it and nothing. Here is a log file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ri6oWeJJLdGPOVbWVQgCqOlFZaP4VmCM/view?usp=sharing

Can someone help?

**UPDATE**: I tried launching Zoom from terminal and it didn't work. However, when I switched to root and tried launching it again, Zoom  launched but I can't do anything.

Comment: Do you get any error when you run Zoom from terminal?

Comment: Now when i run from terminal on non-root i get this:Testing for explicit PulseAudio choice...
...and PulseAudio has been explicitly chosen, so using it.

Comment: When run on root iget this:mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
Testing for explicit PulseAudio choice...
...and PulseAudio has been explicitly chosen, so using it.
No protocol specified
xrdb: Permission denied
xrdb: Can't open display ':0'

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1580376/zoom-and-pulseaudio-audio-distortion-on-audio-run-through-zoom-combine)

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Apparently the problem have been solved. Randomly Live Patch pop up with an error like"machine id can'r enable" and i searched it o internet and solved the problem and then zoom was launching normaly.Also thank you very much for to trying resolve it, I appreciate!

Comment: Hi @AlexandruWorld I am having the exact same problems with zoom. When installing the zoom-client with snap I try to run it and get: "Testing for explicit PulseAudio choice... ...and PulseAudio has been explicitly chosen, so using it" and it doesn't launch. When installing from the .deb file pulled from the zoom website in simply won't launch. However, I don't exactly understand how you solved it. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 6):

You can try uninstalling Zoom that was installed from the .deb package and install a snap one:

```
sudo snap install zoom-client
```

Comment: I did all you said an the results after using the command is error: snap "zoom-client" is not installed

Comment: can you share your system specification ?

Comment: Processor:Intel Celeron 2.4 GHz ,Intel® HD Graphics 500,4 GB RAM,500 GB SSD

Comment: I have edited the command. Can you try again ?

Comment: Yes,downloading rn

Comment: Now it has installed

Comment: Is that working?

Comment: No is not working

Comment: what gpu driver are you using?

Comment: I use Intel Graphics

Answer (score 0):

Open Software & Updates, go on *Livepatch* and if you enable it and get errors like `Failed to read Machine ID` or `this machine ID is already enabled with a different key or is non-unique` this is why zoom doesn't launch.

- For `Failed to read Machine ID` you can try [the solution found here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/693038):

  ```
  sudo touch /etc/machine-id
  sudo systemd-machine-id-setup
  cat /etc/machine-id
  ```
- For `this machine ID is already enabled with a different key or is non-unique` check this question: [Problem trying to use Livepatch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168370/problem-trying-to-use-livepatch)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I get livepatch is not available for this release

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happened when zoom was launched from the GUI, when run from the cli it showed the message `Testing for explicit PulseAudio choice... ...and PulseAudio has been explicitly chosen`
Reinstalling the .deb package or using snap did not solve the problem.

Launched pulseaudio:

```
$ pulseaudio
```

There was a message in the pulseaudio log: `main.c: An error occurred while executing pa_pid_file_create()`, which led me to check the alsamixer utility.

Launched alsamixer

```
$ alsamixer
```

The alsamixer interface showed that everything was muted (MM).
After alsamixer was reconfigured, zoom started.

I hope this solves someone's problem and saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution to maybe not this problem, but after much research I need to share:

Step 1: Find missing packages, in terminal type:
(I think you have to have tried to launch zoom from terminal to get this)

`ldd /opt/zoom/libdvf.so | grep "not found"`

This was my output:

```
        libxcb-icccm.so.4 => not found
        libxcb-render-util.so.0 => not found
```

Step 2: Install missing packages, in terminal:

In my case

`sudo apt install libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-render-util0`

Step 3: Profit (It works!)